# How to copy a specific number of files from a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, docker-container

So I have a Docker container that houses several .txt files named numerically (1.txt, 2.txt etc) and I want to copy the first two files (1,2) to a folder outside of the container without having to hardcode the names of the files into the code.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Consider running your application outside of Docker, or [bind-mounting a host directory](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) into the directory the files will be written, so you don't need a manual "copy" step.

Comment: What do you mean by "folder outside of the container"? on the host? inside another container? on a network path/another machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
docker cp <containerId>:/container_path/1.txt /host/path/target
```

Do the same with other files.